# Identifying items in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am retrieving data from an sqlite database via a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and displaying the results on a `ListView`. The database holds contact information along with an ID string. The two items I am displaying on the listview item are a person's name and their phone number, but I am not displaying the ID string (UUID).

So when the user presses on an item in this listview, how can we identify the corresponding row in the database? The item only contains name and number but not the ID column, meaning I cannot then find the appropriate row in the database.

How can I get around this problem without displaying the long UUID string in the list item?

Comment: Are you using some custom adapter to fill ListView?

Comment: post how you are getting contact information, which data you retrieve and store in temporary object

Comment: You can setTag(position) . I recommend you should take (if not use) the ID. And then, while clicking on the list item, getTag() and fire a query back to the table. (Tell me if it seems confusing to you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your cursor that you pass to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` include the UUID. Just because the cursor contains the UUID doesn't mean that it has to display it. Then when you get the position of the item that was clicked in [OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), move your cursor to this position with [Cursor.moveToPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) and get the UUID with [Cursor.getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29).

Another way (more elegant) is to call [getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getAdapter%28%29) on the AdapterView passed to onItemClick and then cast the adapter as a CursorAdapter and call get [getItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) on the cursor adapter. This should return the cursor object set at the position specified.

Answer (score 1):

The OnItemClickListener's onItemClick() method passes you the position in the list, and Adapter has a method getItem(int position).
Cast the result from getItem() to a Cursor, this will be your cursor initialised to point to the row you clicked, so you can then get any data that was in your original query, regardless of what is in any views.

e.g.:
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phoneNumber")));

Answer (score 1):

In your row layout for your `ListView` add another `TextView` and make this `TextView` invisible.
While initializing your `SimpleCursorAdapter` add `_id` that you are getting from the database to this `TextView`. As this `TextView` is invisible it won't be displayed.

```
String[] from = new String[] { "name", "_id" };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.your_hidden_textview_id };       
SimpleCursorAdapter sadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.ur_row_layout, ur_cursor, from, to);
```

In your `OnItemClick` for `ListView` just use below code to get the Contact ID

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long arg3) {

TextView contactid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_hidden_textview_id);
String Contact_id = contactid .getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: How do I make the textview invisible?

Comment: Add android:visibility="gone" for your textview in row layout

Answer (score 0):

- You can keep your UUID in an array connected with ListView through custom Adapter
- additionally you can store this UUID in view with use of setTag() passing UUID to the view in your custom adapter.